# Inductive algorithm: linear independent versus spanning lists

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

I'm trying to understand a proof in Axler's textbook which states that the size of any linearly independent list cannot exceed the size of any spanning list. He proves it algorithmically. The idea is to start with the full spanning s et $w_1, \ldots, w_n$, add the first element, $u_1$ of the linearly independent set, and then remove some element (say, $w_n$, without loss of generality) so that $u_1, w_1, \ldots, w_{n-1}$ still spans.

The "base step" involves removing one vector and adding $u_1$, which is fine. But then Axler assumes that it holds for steps $1$ through $j-1$. This is something I'be never been able to understand. In induction, I assumed that we say that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$. If I started with $n-1$ and $n \in \{1, \ldots,\}$, then I need to take a base case of $n = 0$. But what exactly is the "zeroth" step of the algorithm? Do nothing, and notice that we still span?

If that is the case, and the $0$th step is just vacuously true and doesn't merit mention, I'm fine with this. Otherwise, should the proof technically address the zeroth step and/or add a $2nd$ step in and then assume $j \geq 2$?

Answer (score 1):

There is a conceptual problem here, which has nothing to do with Linear Algebra. It's about induction. The most common way of proving that all statements from a sequence $\{P(n)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ of statements are true consists of:

- proving that $P(1)$ is true;
- proving that, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, if $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ is also true.

But we can do induction in a slightly different way. It consists of:

- proving that $P(1)$ is true;
- proving that, for each $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$, if $P(n-1)$ is true, then $P(n)$ is also true.

It's actually the same thing, express in a slightly different way. And it's this approach that Axler uses.

Comment: Ok, so the inductive hypothesis is $n-1$ holds for $n > 2$? If so, I think I am all set. Thank you.

Comment: No. The inductive hypothesis is that $P(n-1)$ holds form some $n>1$. And you deduce from this that $P(n)$ holds.